# where can I upload js files to use with url?

Tags: javascript

for exaple if I want to do something like this:

`<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luis72353/stress-relief/master/Util.js"></script>`

Comment: This is an [off-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Answer (score 1):

## Simply by using github , gitlab or any freehoster

e.g. [github pages](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/) or [gitlab pages](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/04/07/gitlab-pages-setup/)